# Using ElementType as field type for plugin in what way do I provide my own data to the modal?

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes

I have been looking at the BaseElementFieldType.php file to try and understand how to use it for my own field type. How do I provide that field type with my own array of data to use? I believe it has to do with the sources,criteria, or elements but it is unclear to me.

Comment: Can you elaborate about what modal exactly are you talking about?

Comment: When using a the BaseElementFieldType it uses the elementSelect form elements.  It is the input type assets uses or categories, or when selecting a relation. I am trying to incorporate that same input but using my own data to populate the modal window from which you can select content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, in that case you'll need to make your own ElementType. You should probably check out https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events - that's meant to be a simple ElementType to serve as an entry point while we get some documentation together.

Also, there are some videos to watch over here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements#creating-new-element-types